# Wifi socket communication with android phone

Tags: android, sockets, wifi, wireless

I would like to ask, how [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=dXYA7uOMWdjOzM&tbnid=a23vqtfsovXw3M%3a&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/WIWO-WIFI-SMART-SOCKET-smartphone-long-distance-control-socket-timing-smart-socket-smartphone-control-smart-socket/117480_1245435925.html&ei=QZZBU-_mOuX_ygP4u4LIAQ&bvm=bv.64125504,d.bGE&psig=AFQjCNEBQiVnpD9Ql2Pou-nYiuhUhnMoxA&ust=1396893621750503) wireless socket communicates with android phone?

I am trying to buy a wireless socket, that I could control through my own code. These all wireless socket already has app developed for them. It is possible to get source code or know how to communicate with this wireless socket and control?

Comment: Bro, if you need the Orvibo device SDK to create your own Android app, ask from the vendor (Orvibo) of the product itself...only if you have already bought the device and the vendor can give the SDK.

Comment: Ok, so best way is to ask vendor for source code? All these sockets don't have standars communication or etc? :)

Comment: Vendor won't give your full sources but instead just SDK (library containing higher-level message structure/protocol/function/etc.) But, you can sniff the messages pass through the socket over WIFI/LAN subnet between the app and the device using Wireshark and figure them out if there is no SDK available or if you want to go cheap.

Comment: So just install wireshark o pc ant try to trace package routes and links?

Comment: PHP code: https://discuss.ninjablocks.com/t/aldi-remote-controlled-power-points-5-july-2014/1793/40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, use Wireshark (or [Shark for Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) if you have an Android device that is rooted). That socket looks very similar to one Aldi Australia are selling (under the brand name Bauhn, but it's actually an Orvibo socket, just rebranded). If it is the same, then check out the sample node.js code I've posted over on [GitHub](https://github.com/Grayda/ninja-allone/blob/master/lib/allone.js) (This code actually controls an Orvibo AllOne, but also controls Orvibo S10 / S20 sockets too)

The short of it is:

- The socket communicates via UDP on port 10000
- You need to know the MAC address of your socket
- You send a discovery packet to which the socket replies
- You then 'subscribe' to the socket in order to control it
- When you send on / off packets to the socket, it replies in turn with it's current state

EDIT: There's a further breakdown of the protocol here: 
http://pastebin.com/0w8N7AJD . Credit goes to Nozza87  on the [Ninja Blocks Forum](http://discuss.ninjablocks.com)

2016 EDIT: The code mentioned is no longer up to date. You can now install node-orvibo, which controls this, the AllOne IR blaster, and can (sort of) do schedules and such. Either install via `npm install --save node-orvibo` or check out the code here: http://github.com/grayda/node-orvibo

Note that the Orvibo S10 / S20 sockets are sold under a variety of names, including Arlec PC180. See the GitHub page for an (incomplete) list of brand names and places to buy them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. You could use wireshark to track packets. But also you could try to user browser's show source ability and look into methods that are being executed.